How to install GLIBCXX_3.4.29 in Miniconda?
Background: I work on a server where I am not a sudo-er. I work with Miniconda, the portable version of Anaconda and install all my libraries there.
Now, I am working on a project that requires me to install either pyg-lib or torch-sparse. And I did install them using their pip commands.
The problem: Both pyg-lib and torch-sparse depend on their choice of GLIBC or GLIBCXX, but my system doesn't have them. I either need GLIBC-2.29 or GLIBCXX-3.4.29.
I am a CS major, doing a Ph.D. in machine learning. I can go through elaborate installation steps, but I would prefer a simpler solution. I am willing to do anything to get my project running. @stackoverflow community, please help me get this installed properly in my local directory without sudo-ing anything.
What I tried: I downloaded GLIBC-2.29 binary, configure it with a local prefix, built it and installed it. But I didn't know where to go from there.

Have you tried installing pyg-lib and torch-sparse from conda?

Alternatively, you could try to build the two from source using your systems glibc version

@FlyingTeller, I did try installing pyg-lib and torch-sparse from conda. Doesn't work. It downgrades my torch to a cpu only version, and then it still doesn't work. I see the same errors: GLIBC-2.29 not found.
I don't know how to build them from source. The GitHub repo of the libraries gives some instructions, but they fail.

What is your server's operation system? Did you set PATH und LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

@Markus, the server has Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. I did set PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, that didn't help. Maybe I didn't set them correctly.


I either need GLIBC-2.29 or GLIBCXX-3.4.29

No: you need both up-to-date GLIBC and up-to-date libstdc++.so.6. GLIBC and GLIBCXX have ~nothing to do with each other.

I downloaded GLIBC-2.29 binary, configure it with a local prefix, built it and installed it. But I didn't know where to go from there.

Read this answer.

For GLIBCXX, the answer is much simpler. The ABI page tells you that you need libstdc++.so.6 from GCC-11.0. So download a build of that, put libstdc++.so.6 into some directory and point LD_LIBRARY_PATH or -rpath to that directory.
Note: miniconda may set LD_LIBRARY_PATH somewhere you don't expect. My advice is to get the binary working to the point where it successfully loads torch outside of miniconda, and once that works, make miniconda work as a separate step.

The original error was /home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xxx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_geometric/typing.py:47: UserWarning: An issue occurred while importing 'pyg-lib'. Disabling its usage. Stacktrace: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xxx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libpyg.so)   warnings.warn(f"An issue occurred while importing 'pyg-lib'. " So, I tried patchelf --set-rpath on /home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xxx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libpyg.so. The patch worked because objdump shows RUNPATH to /path/to/glibc-install.

But the error persists.

"So I tried ...--set-rpath ..." -- the linked answer explains why RPATH is not sufficient.

Not sure there's a solid solution here.
The typical workaround for GLIBC issues in Conda Forge ecosystem to support deployments to outdated systems is to include a sysroot_linux-64 dependency, a minimal repacking of system libraries. However, the problem is that they only cover 2.17 and 2.28. Moreover, one often cannot reliably mix Conda Forge packages with those from main channel and the pyg channel builds prioritize main, pytorch and nvidia. So, that seems like a dead end.
Personally, I'm very reluctant to recommend manipulating LD_LIBRARY_PATH - you basically end up with a software environment that is not transparent and can undermine reproducibility.
I'd probably try running in a container with a modern Linux distro that includes a newer GLIBC. You can still quickly bootstrap the Python environment with Micromamba in a micromamba-docker container (e.g., mambaorg/micromamba:jammy-cuda-12.1.1 has GLIBC 2.35).
In my opinion, this would be the least hacky/most reproducible approach, and that is usually high value for scientific researchers. Even if your HPC admins don't let people run Docker, they do usually allow Singularity, which can run Docker images.
Otherwise, the all-Conda approach should use the following channel configuration, as this is what the official pyg channel uses when building pytorch-sparse and pyg:
environment.yaml
name: pyg
channels:
  - main
  - pytorch
  - nvidia
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.10        # adjust as needed
  - pyg
  - pytorch-sparse
  - pytorch-cuda=12.1  # adjust as needed

